# What is the probability of being wrong in a multiple choice question given that a particular option is certainly not the answer?

Tags: probability

A student is answering a multiple-choice question. He is $100$% certain that a particular option from the three choices is not the correct answer so he is left with two options. Does that mean he is $50$% likely to get it wrong by guessing or is it $33.33$%?

Comment: This is too vague.  Perhaps he is $100\%$ sure that answer $A$ is wrong, and $99.99\%$ sure that answer $B$ is wrong.  There isn't enough information here.

Comment: @lulu It says "by guessing" in the question, which suggests the answer is selected randomly. So I would say $50$% makes most sense.